# Intersection of 3 mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability, self-study

If events A, B, C with probabilities 0.2, 0.4 and 0.3 respectively are all mutually exclusive, would the intersection (ie. A ^ B ^ C) be equal to 0? If, so that would make P(A^B) = 0 as well right?

Any help with this would be great!

Comment: Mutually exclusive events have an empty intersection whether you have two or three such events.

Comment: So I would be correct in saying that the intersection of A, B and C is 0? as well as the intersection of A and B?

Comment: You will be greatly helped if you learn to use correct notation right from the start, e.g. $A\cap B \cap C$ rather than `A ^ B ^ C` and nomenclature. Neither $A\cap B \cap C$ nor `A ^ B ^ C` can _equal_ $0$; they are _sets_ and sets don't take on numerical values. What you want to ask is whether $A\cap B \cap C=\emptyset$ where $\emptyset$ denotes the _empty set_ which has no members. The empty set has _probability_ $0$, the same as the number of its members, but the _empty set_ does not _equal_ $0$; its probability equals $0$. $ A\cap B \cap C=0$ is incorrect, $P(A\cap B \cap C) = 0$ is not.

Comment: sorry, this is my first stats class. So if A, B and C are mutually exclusive, then P(A∩B∩C) = 0, would that mean P(A ∩ B) = 0 as well?

Comment: _In general_, $P(A\cap B \cap C)=0$ does not imply that $P(A\cap B) = 0$. In _your_ problem, it _is_ true that $P(A\cap B)=0$, but this follows not from $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$ but rather from the conditions given to you, viz. "$A$, $B$,...... are mutually exclusive events." (note the complete lack of menion of $C$ in the statement in quotes). More strongly, if $A$ and $B$ are given to be mutually exclusive events and so $P(A\cap B)=0$, then it must be the case that $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$ **regardless of of what $C$ is** and whether it is mutually exclusive with $A$ or $B$ or not.This is because...

Comment: $A\cap B \cap C$ is a _subset_ of $A\cap B$, and there is a general result (quite useful too though most beginners ignore it as just another of those stupid meaningless theorems that mathematicians like to torture us with) that says that if $G$ is a subset of $H$, then $P(G) \leq P(H)$. So, $$(A\cap B \cap C) \subset (A\cap B) \implies P(A\cap B \cap C) \leq P(A\cap B) = 0\implies P(A\cap B \cap C)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider events $A$, $B$, and $C$, where $P(A)=0.2$, $P(B)=0.4$, and $P(C)=0.3$.

$A$, $B$, and $C$ are mutually exclusive (also called pairwise disjoint) if and only if $P(A\cap B)=0$, $P(A\cap C)=0$, and $P(B\cap C)=0$. It's trivial to show that this implies that $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$.

However, if you only know that $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$ (but not that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive), it is not necessarily true that $P(A\cap B)=0$. Consider flipping a coin. Let $A$ and $B$ be the event that the coin shows heads and $C$ be the event that the coin shows tails. Flipping the coin exactly once, $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(\text{heads and heads and tails})=0$. It is impossible to get heads and tails simultaneously with one flip of the coin. However, $P(A\cap B)=P(\text{heads and heads})=\frac{1}{2}\neq0$.

Thus, $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$ does not necessarily imply that $P(A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: the question I'm trying to solve is saying that A, B and C are all mutually exclusive, no ifs. It doesn't give any other information other than their probabilities and that they're mutually exclusive

Comment: That answer is above - the first two sentences. However, it was unclear whether you asked that $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$ implied $P(A\cap B)=0$ or if you asked that all three events being mutually exclusive _also_ implied that $P(A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: My apologies. This is what I meant by my question:


P(A) = 0.2, P(B) = 0.4, P(C) = 0.3; all 3 events are mutually exclusive

What is P(A^B^C)? 

What is P(A^B)?

I'm saying I think the answer is that both = 0. I'm just curious whether this is correct or not.